# How to find an the actual value from a band in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to find the Mean aboveground biomass density (MU) of a specific region from a dataset and print the value. I was able to print the area of the biomass but was not able to print the biomass itself.

Here is the code:

```
var districts = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2");
//var mang_2020 = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-ak7221/assets/2020");
var district = districts.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_NAME','Cidade da Beira'));
//var mang_district = mang_2020.filterBounds(district.geometry())
var styleParams = {
  color: '00909F',
  width: 1.0,
};
//The Biomass dataset and clipping it
var l4b = ee.Image('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI04_B_002').select('MU')
var clipped = l4b.clip(district)
var area = clipped;
Map.addLayer(clipped,{min: 10, max: 250, palette: '440154,414387,2a788e,23a884,7ad151,fde725'},'Mean Biomass');
//Map.addLayer(mang_district, {color: 'blue'}, '2020-2022');
```

and the dataset is here: [Dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LARSE_GEDI_GEDI04_B_002)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image has many pixels with their own distinct values. In order to get *one value*, you need to *reduce* those values of the image, combining them according to some operation into one value. This is done with [`ee.Image.reduceRegion`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregion). To get the mean of all the pixels in your region of interest:

```js
print(
  l4b
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: district,
    })
    .get('MU')
);
```

The result of `reduceRegion()` is a dictionary whose elements are named according to the bands of the image, so I followed it with `.get('MU')` to get the one value of interest (which is also the only value in that dictionary).

Note that I specified `l4b` and not `clipped`. There is no need to clip an image before passing it to `reduceRegion()` since `reduceRegion()` always works within the bounds of a geometry.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Blue Please, mark this answer as accepted because you are using it successfully in your new question on "Forming a new layer ...".

Comment: @xunilk yup did it, sorry didn't know had to do it.